# Angular 1.5: multiple WebSocket connections

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, es6-class

I'm trying to create a service or factory using Angular 1.5 (with ES6) where I could have multiple instances of it, each one having a different connection to a WebSocket (the main purpose of this is a chat system).

I was able to do a service that works for a single WebSocket connection, but given the purpose of this project, I need to be able to connect to different "rooms" but each one of them has a URL with different connection parameters (like so: `ws://localhost:8080/chat/<param1>/<param2>`).

I'm using **angular-websocket** (https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket). Since I'm using ES6 with strict mode, I have to inject `$websocket` from this lib and create immediately an instance of it on the constructor.

So, what I'm looking for is: being able to create multiple WebSocket connections, ideally in a service/factory, where each one of them has its own connection parameters (which would be given on the controller where this service will be instantiated), and then each instance would be able to manage the sending/receiving of new respective "room" messages.

Using ES5, I could probably create a non-singleton service or factory and that could probably solve this problem, but as I'm learning ES6 I would really love to have this solved that way.
Here's my current Chat service class, which currently only is able to handle a static connection, and it's a singleton.

```
export default class ChatService {
  constructor($websocket) {
    'ngInject';

    this._$websocket = $websocket('wss://localhost:8080/chat' + '/param1/param2');
    this.collection = [];

    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this._$websocket.onMessage(this.onMessage);
    this._$websocket.onOpen(this.onOpen);
    this._$websocket.onClose(this.onClose);
    this._$websocket.onError(this.onError);
  }

  onOpen() {
    console.log('Connection open');
  }

  onClose(event) {
    console.log('Connection closed: ', event);
  }

  onError(event) {
    console.log('Connection Error: ', event);
  }

  onMessage(message) {
    this.collection.push(JSON.parse(message.data));
  }

  closeSocket() {
    this._$websocket.close();
  }

  sendMessage(text) {
    // Code to send a message using this connection
  }
}
```

If you have any other suggestion on how to tackle this problem, I'm all ears.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [jquery atmosphere js](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/atmosphere.js-API) for multi socket connection. You can use it.

Exapmle multi connection code :

HTML

```
<button id="b1">
ping s1
</button>

<button id="b2">
ping s1
</button>

<div id="s1">
  <h1>s1 pings</h1>  
  <p></p>
</div>


<div id="s2">
  <h1>s2 pings</h1>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var container;
function Request(sU) {
    this.url = sU;
    this.contentType = 'application/json';
    this.logLevel = 'debug';
    this.trackMessageLength = false;
    this.enableProtocol = false;
    this.enableXDR = true;
    this.transport = 'websocket';
    this.fallbackTransport = 'sse';
    this.reconnectInterval = 5000;
    this.connectTimeout = 30000;
    this.timeout = 60000;
    this.maxReconnectOnClose = 3;
    this.isDetail = false;
    this.suspend = true;
    //this.headers           = {device: $rootScope.imageType}
    this.onOpen = function(response) {
        console.log("connected");
    };

    this.onReopen = function(response) {};

    this.onMessage = function(response) {
        $(container).append("<br>" + response.responseBody );
        console.log(response)
    };

    this.onClientTimeout = function(request) {};


    this.onReconnect = function(request, response) {};

    this.onError = function(response) {};

    this.onClose = function(response) {};
};// Request

function SocketConnector(sU) {
    return {
        request: new Request(sU),
        socket: null,
        closeSocket: function(aciklama) {
            this.socket.close();
        }, //closeSocket
        connectSocket: function() {
                this.socket = $.atmosphere.subscribe(this.request);
            } //connectSocket
    };
};


var socket1  = new SocketConnector('https://echo.websocket.org');
socket1.connectSocket();
$("#b1").click(function(){
  container = "#s1";
    socket1.socket.push(Date.now())
});
var socket2  = new SocketConnector('https://echo.websocket.org');
socket2.connectSocket();
$("#b2").click(function(){
  container = "#s2";
    socket2.socket.push(Date.now())
});
```

You can write this in any angular service js.

Look at [JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/7qkppm9g/1/).

Comment: I didn't know Atmosphere. Thanks for this. Still, I wasn't able to use it. I found an Angular wrapper for it, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work. Even though I have both atmosphere.js and the wrapper imported in the project, it doesn't work...

Comment: @NunoM I edited it for you and create an example on JS Fiddle.

Comment: Kamuran, perhaps I didn't explain myself correctly. I can run your code (thanks for that, btw). What I can't is get Atmosphere.js to run together with the existing Angular wrappers for it, on my ES6 (with Browserify) Angular application. For some reason, the wrapper can't see the original Atmosphere code. I'm pretty sure, once they get to work with each other most of your code can probably be used to set the connections and handle the messaging.

Comment: Karuman, I was finally able to get Atmosphere.js and an Angular wrapper to work together. Your connection settings help me as well, because for some reason, if I had stuck with the basic config (url, transport and contentType) the WebSocket wouldn't connect. Even though your answer help me sort out my main problem, I would like to see if someone can provide me with some input on how to make a non-singleton service when writing an Angular application with ES6. I still haven't manage to get that one. If no further input is provided I'll mark yours as the correct answer, ok? Thanks!

Comment: I am glad to help you NunoM. If you share your wrapper, I can check it for you.

Comment: I used this wrapper: https://github.com/spyboost/angular-atmosphere. The problem was with Atmosphere.js. Once I did `import atmosphere from 'atmosphere.js';` and placed it on the `window`global object (`window.atmosphere = atmosphere;`), both libraries started working together as intended.